# Mod message header notification is missing

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, moderator-tools, notification-bar

I've send four mod messages earlier today (busy morning) and I've just discovered that my fellow Programmers mods didn't get the usual "Yannis released the Kraken again" header notification for any of the messages.

Don't know if that specific notification was supposed to be in the new notifications tab in the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ or stay in the header, but it's nowhere to be found regardless. Other than my four messages (that included two suspensions), we've just tested it again (you know, for science), still no notification. The messages can be seen in `admin/users`, and the suspended users are, well, suspended, so the only problem appears to be the missing mod notification.

---

Well, no notification for the user either, as our guinea pig @BenBrocka reports (thanks ;). That's kind of a big deal, and makes this a bit more urgent than I originally thought.

---

**update**

I've just got a notification for a mod message, yay! And with another test suspension we've confirmed that everything is now back to normal at the user's side, thanks @Lix .

Comment: I wonder if this also means that the people you sent messages to aren't notified. This may be the one notification we don't want to make less prominent.

Comment: @AnnaLear I've edited the question, the messages are shown in `admin/users` and the suspended users are, well, suspended. Unless of course you mean the header notification people get when suspended... Don't know about that...

Comment: @YannisRizos it's still much harder for the mods that didn't suspend (or mods getting a reply!) to find out that info though

Comment: @YannisRizos Yeah, I meant the header notification that the user would normally get.

Comment: @AnnaLear Will find out in a minute, I'm suspending Ben.

Comment: Feel free to (ab)?use my account there for SCIENCE!! $0.02: no matter what, mod messages should be an [OBNOXIOUS ORANGE CAPSLOCK SLIDEDOWN THINGAMAJIG](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/Big-Orange1.png) for the user being targeted.

Comment: @TimManishEarth now now, orange isn't always appropriate, however it should be very noticeable.

Comment: @TimManishEarth Oh, I already tested this with Ben, however if you _really_ want to get suspended, it's not that hard ;)

Comment: @YannisRizos: Not being a programmer ought to be enough to get me suspended from Prog.SE, don't you agree? ;-) [Also, I thought that there were non-lethal _messages_ as well that you can send]

Comment: @TimManishEarth Yes there are non lethal messages, but I always go for the lethal ones... ;P

Comment: A few days ago, a mod did the user contact thing on a site I co-mod, and I never got notified of the message.

Comment: Thanks .... investigating; definitely have a repro - you aren't imagining it.

Comment: @Marc Huh? I never thought I was imagining it ;P

Comment: @YannisRizos: Of course it is happening inside your head, Harry , but why on earth should that mean that it is not real?

Comment: @Tim In my head I've already suspended all the users, so the bug is irrelevant.

Comment: I can confirm any emails requested were sent; the issue here is in the notification UI, not the "send"

Comment: @marc any idea how the notifications work  on mobile? Blue circle thingy or the  same old stuff? And do dismisses sync?

Comment: @Tim it *would* have been "same old stuff", but AFAIK that no longer exists, and everything is "blue circle thingy" - when it works

Comment: @MarcGravell mod messages are blue circle? Shouldn't they be red? They're actionable and important.

Comment: Define `time` and `box` please :P How much time we talking here and what suspension exactly?

Comment: @Lix I'll let you choose the suspension reason, if you let me choose the time. Sounds good? ;P

Comment: I don't use programmers that much at all... feel free to guinea pig me  there... I hope this doesn't look bad on my global SE record ;)

Comment: @Lix You are now suspended... ;)

Comment: woe is me ;)  If you need me, I'll be sulking in the naughty box.

Comment: @Lix So, did you get the notification?

Comment: Yes - I did get it.  You need me to respond or something?

Comment: @Lix Responding should also generate a notification, so yeah go ahead, and then I'll lift the suspension...