# Add "notifications" tab to the mobile global inbox

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications, mobile-web, notification-bar

With the removal of the Big Orange Slidy™ notification bar for badges and privileges, it appears that there is no notification for these at all on the mobile site. (Or at least my last two badges didn't show up on the mobile site with an orange bar like it used to, and there was no notification for it that I could find.)

Can a "notifications" tab and icon be added to the mobile site dropdown?

Comment: Related question: can the mobile inbox also be legitimately referred to as the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™?

Comment: StackExchange™ MiniCollider NotSoSuperDropdown™

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133291/mod-message-header-notification-is-missing#comment369764_133291

Comment: As for its name, see also the reference to ["the Stack Exchange Genuine dropdown"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/revamped-notifications/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The next build will enable the notifications "tab" on mobile.

Comment: First, thank you! Second, I have to kvetch. Sorry! :P As far as I can tell, the new behavior allows you to see either notifications _or_ inbox, but never switch back and forth between the two. Also, unless you actually get a notification, there is no way to see previous notifications. Why was this behavior chosen?

Comment: @HodofHod - space; there's not much of it available on the mobile site.  Notifications are low priority, so you can only see them if you have *new* ones on mobile.  We're still looking at the design, may be some more tweaks coming down today.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Keep us posted!

Comment: Random thought: The "show more inbox messages" link disappears once you click it and the inbox expands.  Could you replace that link at the bottom with a "view notifications" link?  I don't know how intuitive that really is, though.